# Geoserver Reprojection Results in Northerly Shift Compared to GDAL

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system

I have data in a postgresql data store in EPSG:2163 and am displaying that using OpenLayers in EPSG:3857. This results in a ~25 km northerly shift when displayed either in QGIS or OpenLayers.

To test the reprojection I used GDAL and the Geoserver reprojection console, which confirmed that the x-coordinates were reprojecting correctly but the y-coordinates were artificially high.

**GDAL:**
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:2163 -t_srs EPSG:3857
1494718.24465831 -1025289.47657808

output = -9310869.18028598 4090931.77295946 0 (this displays correctly).

**Geoserver:**
[Reprojection Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhRFM.jpg)

output =-9310869.180285975 4115158.942481106 (this displays north of expected).

Resulting in a difference of 24.2 km.

It seems to me that this a projection problem within Geoserver, any ideas what the problem is or how I can get around this? If I reproject my source data in postgresql to EPSG:3857, there are no projection problems but I want to keep my source data in EPSG:2163.

Comment: I noticed that there is a difference in the coordinate system definition for EPSG:3857 between GDAL and Geoserver. GS = UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295] and GDAL = UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433, though it seems like a very slight rounding difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An offset of about 20 km to the North is usual between the ellipsoidal and the special Google spherical version of Mercator. I guess that recent versions of GDAL do it right.

Feel free to make a bug report at Geoserver.

In the meantime, avoid EPSG:3857 if possible, or do the reprojection inside Postgis or GDAL.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating views for my layers in postgres and reprojecting the geometry column to 3857. Then I publish the view instead of the table. Something like this:CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [VIEW_NAME] AS 
 SELECT st_transform(geometry, 3857) AS geometry, [FIELD_1], [FIELD_N]
   FROM [TABLE_NAME];